# Is 苦手 etymologically related to 苦い？

Tags: etymology

Is 苦手 etymologically related to 苦い？ Does the former derive from the latter? Does the fact that they have the same root kanji make this obvious, or is there something about 手 that also gives me information about the word? I'd be doubly happy to learn that there's some pattern I haven't yet learned.

I don't own the *Nihongogen*, so I can't look it up there, and Wiktionary doesn't connect the two.

I'm guessing I'm asking something fairly obvious if I keep learning, but I admit my curiosity is getting the better of me now.

Comment: [Marking this complete for now, but if anyone has any additional information, I would still very much appreciate it!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting to this [website](https://www.waraerujd.com/blank-581) (in Japanese):

> 苦手とは、不得意であることやつきあいにくい相手を意味する。「苦い」は味覚の一種だが、甘・塩・酢・苦の基本味覚の中でもヒール（悪役）を演じているように、「苦い」は、不愉快である、つらい、苦しいといった感覚、感情を言い表すのに使う。「苦手」は、取り扱ったり、つきあったりするのが難しいので、できるなら相手にしたくない（きらいな）対象を意味する。例えば「勝負事は苦手です」と言えば、「いつもコロ負けしているので賭け事に手を出したくない」ということ。「苦手」を直訳すると、「なめると苦い味のする手」で、漢方薬を扱っている薬剤師の手みたいなことになるが、この解釈は冗談ではなく、江戸時代に「苦手」と言えば、「爪が苦く毒を持ち、触れると腹痛を抑えたり、ヘビをつかまえたりできる手」を意味していた。まさに、腹痛の「手当て」であり、ヘビを素手で捕らえる「ゴッドハンド」だった。しかし、そんなパワーを持っていたにしても、いまどき「手が苦いから」などと解釈する人もいないので、「手」が「相手」や「傾向」の意味に解釈されて現在の「苦手」の使い方に落ち着いたものと思われる。

In short, 苦手 in the Edo period used to refer to the hand of the pharmacist(serving traditional Chinese medicine) who put bitter drugs/poison on their nails and thereby could heal stomach-ache by touching or could catch snakes. Even those the meaning changed today, the 苦 did in fact mean 苦い.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how authoritative that website is? Is this a folk etymology, or something that is more secured in history? Seems plausible enough.

Comment: Well, if I were to translate the website, I'd focus on the "supernatural" meaning which can actually be confirmed by several (free online versions of) reviewed Japanese dictionaries, e.g. https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%8B%A6%E6%89%8B-591113 I didn't know about this historical usage of the word, I'm glad to learn more about the Japanese language at this age (late 30s). However I have to point out "drugs on the nails" part is the website author's own research which doesn't cite any literature. Which is to say, the etymology seems to be unclear.

Comment: @nodakai The strange thing is that having powerful hands seems to be the opposite of being bad at something!